# How to get SQL to show unmatched criteria in the results?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with thousands of customers. They all have unique customer ID.

From another different system I have received a list of customer ID's and I would like to know which of these ID's cannot be found in my database.

My query currently is something like this

```
select ID
from table
where ID in ('A1', 'A2', 'A3', ... 'A6499', 'A6500')
```

From the search condition, how do I get the *unmatched* search values into the result set?
I know how I would do this if the search criteria data already existed in the same database. Are there any other options than making a temporary table and joining with it?

My database will contain more values than A6500, for example A7500. I do not want to get this value in my result set.

Comment: Perhaps as simple as NOT IN?

Comment: That would return the ID's from my database that do not match. But I want to know from the search criteria which do not match. For example my DB could contain ID 'A7500' and I would not want to get it in the results.

Comment: Well...your question is so vague all I can do is guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql):

```
SELECT t.ID
FROM (VALUES ('A1'), ('A2'), ('A3')) AS t(ID)   
LEFT JOIN table ON t.ID = table.ID
WHERE table.ID IS NULL
```

Or if you get the ids as a comma delimited string use [`string_split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) (2016+) or a string splitting udf for lower versions - I recommend Jeff Moden's [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/):

```
SELECT value
FROM STRING_SPLIT('A1,A2,A3', ',') AS t  
LEFT JOIN table ON t.value = table.ID
WHERE table.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for but could not find the means to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Using a explicit `VALUES`, you can write more than 1000 values, which is the `IN` limit.

```
;WITH OtherDatabaseIDs AS
(
    SELECT
        V.*
    FROM
        (VALUES 
         (1000),
         --... as many records as you want
         (2500)) V(OtherDatabaseID)
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    OtherDatabaseIDs AS T
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table AS O WHERE T.OtherDatabaseID = O.ID)
```

Comment: Thanks also for the helpful comment!